# Drupal search block customizing

Tags: drupal

I have my block template **block.tpl.php**

```
<div class="block">
    <?php print $content ?>
</div>
```

And I want to change block wrapper for search form

```
<div class="block search">
    <?php print $content ?>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use **block-search.tpl.php** but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you cleared the cache after saving your changes?

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in Drupal - you can override specific template(block-search.tpl.php) in theme when you override general template(block.tpl.php).

Other thing is that probably your cache is not cleared - try

And [here](http://www.pixelclever.com/how-theme-specific-blocks-drupal) you have some nice description how to check other things that could failed.